# What are the proper ways to troubleshoot js drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I need to troubleshoot a problem with javascript drag and drop and need some counsel as far as the proper way to do it.  I have some experience working in the console and often using inspect in Chrome browser.  I don't mind installing other browser extensions if they will help.  The problem is a drag and drop function that works in some circumstances and not in others.  This takes place on two separate pages of the same type in a Rails application that should have all the same javascript present.  My plan of attack is the following but feel free to advise me otherwise:

1. Find the javascript code responsible for the drag and drop.  How do I do that?
2. Debug the code.  I think by setting breakpoints and stepping through it and comparing it on two separate pages, one where it's working and the other where it's not.  Will I run into problems debugging, though, since drag and drop requires me to hold down the mouse button and traverse the tracking pad at the same time and the instant I stop I will no longer be running through the drag and drop code?

EDIT:  I found Firebug's Profile tab in Firefox and using that I can see that in the page that works just mousing over a blank part of the page fires off 5 js functions, while nothing happens doing the same on the other page.  So apparently the working page is listening for events that the non-working page is not, though the pages should be identical in that aspect as they are generated from the same code.  Now the question is how can I find out why these listeners aren't there on the non-working page?

Comment: Debugging is the best way to troubleshoot any problem

Comment: putting breakpoints in any interactive part of the code will change the behaviour of said code